# Trying to use a String Variable instead of Quoted Test. Message: exit status 1 initializer fails to determine size of 'data'

Tags: c++, arduino

I have built 2 Arduino Nano Transceivers that are communicating perfectly.
I am having trouble when I try to use a String Variable as opposed to Quoted Text.

This compiles and works fine:

```
uint8_t data[] = "Hello World";
nrf24.send(data, sizeof(data));
```

This fails to compile:

```
String myMessage = "Hello World";
uint8_t data[] = myMessage;
nrf24.send(data, sizeof(data));
```

Error message I get:  exit status 1 initializer fails to determine size of 'data'

I assume that it is failing because my String is not a Character Array. I have tried many times to convert this so as to be accepted. I can't figure it out. All examples on stackoverflow don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String myMessage = "Hello World";
nrf24.send(myMessage.c_str(), myMessage.length());
```

Comment: This is a good answer for standard C++. But I'm not sure it will work on the Arduino which is not true C++.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Didn't work, same error message. Pulling my hair out. Spent hours on this.

Comment: @RAPTORp the error message in the answered code can't be the same, there is no the data variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize an array from a `String` variable, only from a string literal. The size of the array has to be known at compile time, and you don't get that with a `String` variable, so you would have to allocate the array dynamically at runtime instead, eg:

```cpp
String myMessage = "Hello World";
size_t len = myMessage.length() + 1;
uint8_t *data = new uint8_t[len];
myMessage.getBytes(data, len);
nrf24.send(data, len);
delete[] data;
```

Which can be simplified by getting rid of the array altogether:

```cpp
String myMessage = "Hello World";
nrf24.send(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(myMessage.c_str()), myMessage.length()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arduino C++ is not a full C++ implementation. I don't know much about the String class on the Arduino. The class itself may have a function for doing this conversion for you or more likely to return a pointer to the buffer storing the data in the string. Possibly named something like ToArray or GetBuffer.

I doubt you need to copy the data into a separate array. Instead you want to pass the address of the first byte of the string and the length of the string. While `strlen()` is often used to get the length of the string. My guess is that the String class provides a function to return this for you. Maybe GetLength() or Length().

Comment: The documentation of the Arduino classes is available online, so no need for guessing the names: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to improve my answer now. Thanks for the info UnholySheep. Hopefully the other answer resolved the issue.

Comment: I appreciate that info, but I'm still stuck. uint8_t likes quoted text, but doesn't like a String variable. I've tried everythin I can think of. I don't know how to convert the Variable into the uint8_t that it will understand. I've tried 50+ different examples, still nothing.